# capybara-webkit jQuery.active not working with xvfb

Tags: jquery, qt, headless, capybara-webkit, xvfb

I have a problem with capybara-webkit + xvfb on my ubuntu systems/ci. OSX running fine.

QT5 installed.

I'm using the wait_for_ajax method (https://thoughtbot.com/blog/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara)

Ubuntu returns: undefined method `zero?' for nil:NilClass

I tried headless gem, I tried xvbf-run - both running in the same error. It feels like it is not using the webkit driver, and instead using plain capybara.

*(running in two other visible failures, which I do not have on osx - but I could rewrite these, but jQuery.active I can not)*

In my rails_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  [...]
  require 'capybara/webkit'
  require 'headless'
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
end

Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  # config.debug = true

  # Timeout if requests take longer than 5 seconds
  config.timeout = 5

  # Don't load images
  config.skip_image_loading
end
```

also I tried

```
config.around(:each, js: true) do |example|
  Headless.ly do
    example.run
  end
end
```

so I'm out of ideas how to fix it - anyone run in the same problem before, and have any hint for me?

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the problem: webpack - on my local machine i used webpack-dev-server on the CI the production.config - In the end it loaded the wrong file, and now js was loaded.